# Interpolation of $\Pi_\Sigma(N)$

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, interpolation

I am asking this question out of curiosity, there is not really a particular reason behind this question.

### $\Pi_\Sigma$:-

I created this function which I call the Factor-Sum function. I don't know if this function is a popular function used by mathematicians or not, so I am just calling it my own.

So I defined,

$\Pi_\Sigma(N)=
\begin{cases}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}{p_i}, & \text{if}N=\prod_{i=1}^{n}{p_i}^{a_i} \\N, & \text{if} N=0,1 \\-\Pi_\Sigma(|N|), & \text{if} N<0 \end{cases}$

So this is an odd function which gives the input back when given a prime or $0$ or $1$ and gives the sum of the prime factors when given a composite.

#### For example:-

●$\Pi_\Sigma(13)=13$

●$\Pi_\Sigma(18)=2+3+3=8$

●$\Pi_\Sigma(-18)=-8$

### Interpolation of $\Pi_\Sigma$:-

So $\operatorname{Dom}(\Pi_\Sigma)=\mathbb{Z}$

I want to extend the domain of $\Pi_\Sigma$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I have estimated few non-integer values of the function using newton forward formula-

$f(a+hu)=f(a)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{u!}{n!(u-n)!}\Delta^nf(a)$

But it doesn't give an accurate or an estimated general formula for $\Pi_\Sigma$ for any real $N$.

I don't want interpolations like Peicewise constant interpolation or Linear interpolation which gives sharp edges in the graph of the function.

I want an interpolation of $\Pi_\Sigma$ such that it becomes differentiable everywhere.(Such as polynomial interpolation, spline interpolation)

Any help would be appreciated.

*(I don't really know much about interpolation that's why I need help.)*

Comment: If you succeeded to find a general formula of $\Pi_{\Sigma}$ for any real $N$, you could predict prime numbers, which is impossible. Indeed, $\Pi_{\Sigma}(p)$ for $p$ large prime number can be seen as local maximum
$$\Pi_{\Sigma}(p) > \Pi_{\Sigma}(n) \qquad \text{for } n\in (p -N, p+N)$$
Hence, by observing the distribution of $\Pi_{\Sigma}(n)$ and study all local maximum point, you could predict the existence of prime number.

Comment: @NN2, thanks for the response. Your comment gave me new knowledge about this function, but you shouldn't have said that predicting primes is impossible becuase it is not proven.

Comment: @NN2, how is $\Pi_\Sigma(p)>\Pi_\Sigma(n)$? If $p$ is a prime then $\Pi_\Sigma(p)=1$!

Comment: If $N = p$ is a prime, then $N = p^1$ according to your definition
$$\Pi_\Sigma(N)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}{p_i} = p^1 = p $$

Besides, $\Pi_\Sigma(N)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}{p_i}  \le \prod_{i=1}^{n}{p_i}^{a_i}$, the equality occurs only if $N$ is a prime.

Comment: We notice that if $N = p$ a prime, then $N-1, N+1$ are very smaller compared to $N = p$ (for example, $N-1$ is even, so $\Pi_{\Sigma}(N) $ is at least twice smaller than $N$
Suppose we succeed to build the funtion $\Pi(N)$, we create a method to find prime numbers from  the funtion $\Pi(N)$ (a method simpler than the one I proposed in the first comment). If the funtion $\Pi(N) = N$, then $N$ is a prime number.

Comment: @NN2, I am really really sorry, I legit don't get it that why I made the second comment, it is so foolish. I think my brain was lagging during that moment, I actually knew that $\Pi_\Sigma(p)=p$ if $p$ is a prime, in fact that was one of the things I purposefully added in the function.